# Performing Chi-Squared Test in Python

Tags: python-3.x, chi-squared

Is there a way to perform the chi-squared test of independence without having the expected value?

Comment: If you can assume the data is normally distributed, you can use an expected value as the mean of the observations. If not, you cannot use chi-squared analysis. The issue isn't not having an expected value.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure as to what type of data you are looking at, but perhaps you could try looking at the documentation for scipy library listed [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html). The scipy library has a chi-squared function which may be of use to you

```
from scipy.stats import chisquare  
chisquare([ <your data points>])
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried using this, but it doesn't produce p-value if we don't have the expected value.

Comment: @JinayJani, the documentation pretty clearly shows you're wrong on that. The f_exp is by default just the mean of the data for each element, and it will provide a p value (at least in modern SciPy versions).

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh,  Power_divergenceResult(statistic=838.78434226260651, pvalue=nan) This is the output I am getting.

Comment: @JinayJani if it's not too much trouble, could we see the data being fed into the function?

Comment: @JinayJani Can you provide sample data? There may also be an overflow or underflow somewhere. Joel is perfectly right here.

Comment: here's the sample data @AlexanderHuszagh [ 46.085  46.329  47.727 ...,  45.364  46.815  46.559]. It has 24,000 entires.

Comment: @JinayJani, yeah overflow or underflow is likely. I can reproduce this with `a = np.random.rand(24000) * 5e300; chisquare(a)`. I would normalize your data before doing any statistical measures to ensure no overflow occurs. SciPy should warning you with something like `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract`.

Comment: 'import numpy as np
import scipy.stats

data = np.loadtxt('ABC.txt')
n = len(data)
ci = scipy.stats.chisquare(data,ddof=n )
print(ci)'

This is the code I have written.